# PHP not working while selecting multiple columns from a table with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I am using Apache 2.2. When I am trying to run it my browser is failing to run it, it's showing:

```
 This webpage is not available
 The connection to localhost was interrupted.
 Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/db.inc.php' ;
$sql="select post_id,post_title,post_desc,post_date,course,semester,firstname,lastname FROM wbut_forum_posts left join users on post_by = email ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql );

if (!$result)
{
    include_once "wall.html.php";
    echo'<tr><td align="center"> OOOOPPPPPSSS!!!SORRY,UNABLE TO DISPLAY LATEST 25 TOPICS</td></tr>';
    exit();
}
$allposts = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $allposts[] = array( 'p_id' => $row['post_id'],'p_title' => $row['post_title'],'p_desc' => $row['post_desc'],'p_date' => $row['post_date'],'p_course' => $row['course'],'p_semester' => $row['semester'],'p_firstname' => $row['firstname'],'p_lastname' => $row['lastname']);
}
foreach ($allposts as $posts) :
?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr>
<td align="left"> <span class="style5"><?php echo $posts[p_firstname] . " " . $posts[p_laststname] ; ?></span></td>
<?php
 $id=urlencode($posts[p_id]);
 $title=urlencode($posts[p_title]);
 $date=urlencode($posts[p_date]);
 $course=urlencode($posts[p_course]);
 $semester=urlencode($posts[p_semester]);
 $firstname=urlencode($posts[p_firstname]);
 $lastname=urlencode($posts[p_lastname]);
 ?>
 <td align="center" >
        <a href="view.html.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>&amp;title=<?php echo "$title" ?>&amp;date=<?php echo "$date" ?>&amp;course=<?php echo "$course" ?>&amp;semester=<?php echo "$semester" ?>&amp;firstname=<?php echo "$firstname" ?>&amp;lastname=<?php echo "$lastname" ?>&amp;" title="VIEW POST">
            VIEW THE FULL POST AND REPLY HERE
        </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <span class="style6"><?php echo $posts[p_title] ; ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $posts[p_date] ; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
        <PRE>RELATED COURSE  : <span class="style7"><?php echo $posts[p_course] ; ?></span> AND RELATED SEMESTER :  <?php echo $posts[p_semester] ; ?></PRE>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span class="style17"><?php echo $posts[p_desc] ; ?></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The error:

```
This webpage is not available
The connection to localhost was interrupted.
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

Is it an Apache problem? If so then how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like your server is having the hiccups when running your script? Have you checked your log files?

Comment: no.how to check it?

Comment: Depends on what kind of server you are running (XAMP/MAMP other?). Best to google around a bit or check the documentation. There are lots of other 'Error 101' questions here on StackOverflow, may be worth to check them as well?

Comment: i have checked them all..i am using apache 2.2

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. First try to find the logfiles and check them. Are you able to visit other pages on the same server? E.g. Put a regular HTML file on the server and try to open that inside your browser. Empty your Browser-cache, just to be sure.

Comment: yes i rest of my website code is working fine..and i dont know how to check log files..can u tell me please?

Comment: Sorry, no, depends on your system, platform and configuration just try this: http://bit.ly/10n03mz and this http://bit.ly/10n0rl9

Comment: got it..what to check

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that can crop up now and then with Apache, especially where it has been packaged into a stack such as XAMPP or WAMP. I have found the best option in these instances is to uninstall the software and reinstall a clean copy. Can't confirm exactly what the root cause is but I have encountered instances where this happens and only affects a small subset of the PHP files in an application and the re-installation of the Apache stack fixes it.